# jQuery Mobile loading gif not animating in Windows 7 PhoneGap application

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing windows phone application using phonegap and jquery mobile.Everything works fine except for the loading image.The loading gif doesn't animate.Are there any workarounds so that jquery mobile loading image animates in windows phone 7 application?

Comment: I have seen this too. The page is drawn, with the box for the animated gif, but the image isn't rendered. (Jquery 1.7.2, JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 and cordova 2.9) It could be down to fakeFixLoader and reported viewport dimensions...